# show/hide div (back to prev)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have three div :

```
  <div class="col-xs-6" id="divname1" style="display: none;">

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="button2" onclick="RadioCheck()">Dalej</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="button" onclick="BackFunction()">Cofnij</button>

        </form>         
  </div>


  <div class="col-xs-6" id="divname2" style="display: none;">

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="button2" onclick="RadioCheck()">Dalej</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="button" onclick="BackFunction()">Cofnij</button>

        </form>         
  </div>


  <div class="col-xs-6" id="divname3" style="display: none;">

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="button2" onclick="RadioCheck()">Dalej</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="button" onclick="BackFunction()">Cofnij</button>

        </form>         
  </div>
```

using js i hide/show them clicking via button2

example:

```
if (x = divchecked)
{
    document.getElementById('somediv').style.display = 'block' ;

    var ele = document.getElementById("buttonfromdiv");
    ele.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");

}

    if (x = chec.checked)
    {
        document.getElementById('divsome2').style.display = 'block' ;

        var ele = document.getElementById("buttonchecked");
        ele.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
    }
```

The name using there is only example and i think dont work to run it from this code (in my code there is still working, but that its not needed here).

I need to write script : when i click on button "cofnij",
i get the id of div where is this button now, hide this div, and back to prev...

Problem via example:

We have main div where we click some radius and click next (dalej).
Now one div is showing named divsecond (ex.),
We click on "cofnij" button and this div change proporty to hide.

The problem is the div who is showing is more then 200...
So i need to script that automaticly get the currently div id, hide this div, unlock button from first div

Comment: A working jsFiddle will be great, but first, do you have a typo in `if (x = chec.checked)`? Usually we compare variables' value in `if()` statements, and not assigning values there...

Comment: You can add a tag to all the divs to group them, so you can fetch them all by tag name. Then loop through each element and depending on the div id, do the required action. However i would use binding to solve problems like this, are you able to use an external library such as knockout?

Comment: HotTowelie, yea. There will be no problem using other lib.

Narxx, only this method come to my head when i start writing this code :d
Now i dont have time to reabuild all ; /

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution, using no id's on either the buttons nor the div, they still "know" to which div each button belong

```js
var checkbuttons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-check]');
var backbuttons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-back]');

for (var i = 0; i < backbuttons.length; i++) {
  
  checkbuttons[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){
    if (e.target.parentElement.style.backgroundColor == 'red') {
      e.target.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = '';
    } else {
      e.target.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = 'red'
    }
  });

  backbuttons[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){    
    if (e.target.parentElement.style.backgroundColor == 'red') {
      e.target.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = 'lime';
    }    
  });
  
}
```

```css
[data-displaynone] {
  /* display: none; */
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-6" data-displaynone>

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-check>Dalej</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-back>Cofnij</button>
</div>


<div class="col-xs-6" data-displaynone>

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-check>Dalej</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-back>Cofnij</button>
</div>


<div class="col-xs-6" data-displaynone>

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-check>Dalej</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-back>Cofnij</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you moddify your code to :
I click Dalej, then this div have red color,
Now i click cofnij and this red background will be lime.

This will be great :)

Comment: @Tomasz Updated .. is this how you want?

Comment: Yes. Thanks mate !